# How does the bang operator (!) work against bits?

Tags: bit-manipulation, bit

I've been asked to compute `!x` without using `!`.

Examples:

> bang(3) = 0
>   bang(0) = 1

The legal operations: `~`, `$`, `|`, `^`, `+`, `<<`, `>>`

I don't understand what a bang does? I thought it was a factorial.

Comment: Specifying which language you're using would help.

Comment: In C, `((x >> 31) | ((~x + 1) >> 31)) + 1`

Answer (score 1):

If in C, your "!" is a boolean inverse of its argument.  So, !0 yields 1 and 1(anything else) yields 0.  The "~" is the bitwise version of it, essentially flipping each bit in the (following) number - much easier to understand if you constrain yourself to unsigned numbers.

!x can be emulated with things like (x?1:0) - which isn't in your list - and the && and || operators - which also aren't in your list.  "$" isn't an operator in C, so I'm a bit puzzled by that one - what language are you in?  You might have some luck using the | and looping through all the bits to figure out if *any* are set, after that point using the bitwise operators on just your resulting 1 bit make it pretty easy to emulate "!".

I could just lay it out, but if you're taking a class, the struggle is where most of the gain is for this particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

The bang operator acts as a boolean function. You might get an error message if you try to perform bitwise operations on the results. What Ryan suggests is a way of getting around that, and still use bitwise operators on the result without being blocked by bitwise-boolean warnings.

Unrelated, not adding the 1 at the end leaves a useful mask that's either all ones (thanks to the trailing zeroes during the right-shift) or all zeroes, depending on whether x is zero or non-zero.

Answer (score -1):

`!` is the logical negation operator. Your favorite search engine will tell you more.